# Bundling Data files with PyInstaller 2.1 and MEIPASS error --onefile

Tags: python, build, environment-variables, exe, pyinstaller

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741) has been asked before and I can't seem to get my PyInstaller to work correctly.  I have invoked the following code in my mainscript.py file:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

When I run the py file (within IDLE), my app runs perfectly and loads all of the data files.  However, when I bundle it with PyInstaller 2.1 (one file method) I get the following error after the exe builds:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 37, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path   
specified: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI188722\\eggs/*.*'
```

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong?  Thanks!

** EDIT **

Here is exactly what I want to do.

My main script has a setup (imports) that look like below.  Essentially I want to be able to have Matplotlib, Basemap, and resource path all in it:

```
import os,sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WX')
import wx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import FigureCanvasWx as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Calculate_Distance # A personal py file of mine

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

bmap=wx.Bitmap(resource_path('test_image.png'))

print 'hello'
```

I am using PyInstaller 2.1.  I am also using Python 2.7.5 (32 bit).  My OS is Windows 8 (64bit).  My Matplotlib is 1.3.0 and Basemap is 1.0.6.  Wxpython is 2.8.12.1 (Unicode).

I go to command and do: `> pyinstaller myscript.py`.  This generates my .spec file which I slightly edit.  Below is my edited spec file:

```
data_files = [('Calculate_Distance.py', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\MyFolder\\Calculate_Distance.py',
              'DATA'), ('test_image.png', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\MyFolder\\test_image.png',
              'DATA')]

includes = []
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']
packages = []
dll_excludes = []
dll_includes = []

a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\MyFolder','C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\mpl_toolkits\\basemap\\*'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries - dll_excludes + dll_includes + data_files,          
          name='MyApplication.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='MyApplication')
```

I want this to be a one-file executable so the data files should be packed within the executable.  On other pyinstallers I usually haven't had issues with the MEIPASS.  However, I need to use 2.1 because of Matplotlib and Basemap.  If someone can build this exe perfectly -- can you please tell me what I need to adjust?  Thanks!

****EDIT****

If anyone can figure out how to do this with py2exe -- that would be great too.  Any way that I can get this into a single executable would be worth it!

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem here, but the pypi version of Pyinstaller 2.1 seems to have a bunch of bugs, try using the git version at https://github.com/pyinstaller.

Comment: I downloaded the one straight of pyinstaller.org -- is this the same as getting it from pypi?

Comment: I would expect so. They are both the 2.1 release version.

Comment: github version did not help

Answer (score 12):

I think I see the problem. You're not feeding data_files into your Analysis object. 
Here's how I add my data files in my .spec file:

```
a = Analysis(....)
a.datas += [('7z.dll', '7z.dll', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('7z.exe', '7z.exe', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('collection.xml', 'collection.xml', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('License.html', 'License.html', 'DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts + [('O', '', 'OPTION')],
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'blah.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=False,
          console=True,
          icon=r'..\NCM.ico')
```

Notice I'm not using COLLECT() at all.

If you checkout the 2.1 documentation at: [PyInstaller Spec File Operation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#spec-file-operation) you'll notice that COLLECT() isn't used for --onefile mode.

If you look at the extracted directory pointed at by sys._MEIPASS you'll probably notice that with your spec file that the data file simply isn't there at all.

I hope this helps.