# using PyInstaller as Installer

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyinstaller

Is it possible to do a two steps decompression with PyInstaller? 
e.g. it can decompress archived files from itself as needed, like InnoSetup, Nullsoft Installer (NSIS).

For --onefile exe generated with PyInstaller, everything is decompressed at invocation runtime, and it takes a lot of time, if there's a lot of bundled datafile.

What I trying to do is to replicate InnoSetup with PyInstaller+PyQt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You can bundle installer files by appending to a.data in your spec file.  Then at runtime your data files will be in the MEIPASS folder and you can copy them wherever you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20088482/259538