# pyinstaller: AttributeError module 'webbot' has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, attributeerror

this question has come up a lot of times, but unfortunatelly none of them was my case but one (at first).
[How to use pyInstaller to completely pack all the necessary Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144170/how-to-use-pyinstaller-to-completely-pack-all-the-necessary-library][1])

I have written a script in Python using multiple libraries, one of them being the webbot module. I managed to convert my script to an .exe file but when I tried to run the .exe the following error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "TM.py", line 132, in <module>
    File "site-packages\webbot\webbot.py", line 45, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]The system could not find the path...
```

Then I followed the instructions in the above link.

Then I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "TM3.py", line 12, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'webbot' has no attribute 'data'
[9292] Failed to execute script TM3
```

Where line 12 is:

```
webbot.data.path.append(r'webbot_master_data')
```

Could someone help me over here?

### Thanks in advance

Using:

Windows: 10

PyInstaller: 3.4

Python: 3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

In this case what I had to do is simply copy the file of the webbot module to the same folder, in which my .exe file is being created. It is in this folder that other modules might me saved as well.

After copying the file there, the execution should run. Howeverthis might be more of a workaround than a solution, so I am not going to accept my answer as an answer.